# How can I initialize Chrome Remote web driver using WebDriverManager while passing ChromeOptions and a Selenium Grid standalone server url?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, webdrivermanager-java

Trying to initialize a Chrome Remote web driver using WebDriverManager, while passing ChromeOptions and a Selenium Grid standalone server URL using Java.
From online examples;
Passing Chrome options would look like this:

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
RemoteWebDriver remoteWebDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
threadLocalDriver.set(remoteWebDriver);
```

Passing the hub URL for the selenium grid standalone server would look like this:

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
RemoteWebDriver remoteWebDriver = ((RemoteWebDriver) WebDriverManager
                                           .chromedriver()
                                           .remoteAddress(hubURL)
                                           .create());
threadLocalDriver.set(remoteWebDriver);
```

How can I pass both to a RemoteWebDriver object?

Thanks

EDIT:

Here is my code. I am getting an error from **create()** method
**[main] ERROR io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager - There was an error creating WebDriver object for Chrome
io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.config.WebDriverManagerException: Timeout of 30 seconds creating WebDriver object**

public void createDriver() throws IOException {

```
    ChromeOptions options = getPlatformSpecificOptions();
    logger.info("Driver options: " + options.toString());
    
        String hubURL = "http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub";
        
        WebDriver driver = WebDriverManager.chromedriver()
                .capabilities(options)
                .remoteAddress(hubURL)
                .create();           
        threadLocalDriver.set(((RemoteWebDriver) driver));
        
    }
    TestHelper.setPlatform(PLATFORM);
}
```

---

Comment: did you solve the Timeout error please?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the method capabilities() for that:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--headless");
WebDriver driver = WebDriverManager.chromedriver()                        
                                   .capabilities(options)
                                   .remoteAddress(hubURL)
                                   .create();
```

Also calling setup() is not needed as it is called by create() method.

Comment: Thank you Simon for your response.

Tried your code. I am getting this error:

**[main] ERROR io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager - There was an error creating WebDriver object for Chrome
io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.config.WebDriverManagerException: Timeout of 30 seconds creating WebDriver object 
at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.webdriver.WebDriverCreator.createRemoteWebDriver(WebDriverCreator.java:95)
 **
Added my code in the question. Maybe you'll have more ideas as to where this error comes from.
Truly appreciate your help!